# UWP toggle switch toggles other items in the view only

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I know this is maybe very basic to you, but excuse me as am new in UWP .

i has very basic List of objects rendered using Listview

```
                <ListView  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BorderBrush="#FF141EE4"  Name="BillsList"
                  SelectionChanged="BillsList_SelectionChanged"
                  FontFamily="Arial" 
                   FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="250" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="2">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BookTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding  bilng_date, Converter={StaticResource billingDateFormatter }}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="الدورة" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="WalkTxt"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding cl_blnce}"  FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="القيمة" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="paymentTxt"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding payment_no}"  FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="رقم الفاتورة" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CollectionState" Text="{Binding delivery_st , Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToColorConverter}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16"  FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="حاله الفاتوره" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                                <ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="4" IsOn="False" Toggled="AddToBillsList_Toggled" OffContent="إضافه لقائمه التحصيل" OnContent="حذف من قائمه التحصيل" Visibility="{Binding delivery_st, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToCollection}}"  />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>-->
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
```

the AddToBillsList_Toggled function

```
private void AddToBillsList_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleSwitch toggle = sender as ToggleSwitch;
        if (toggle != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataContext = toggle.DataContext;
                var dataItem = (HAND_MH_ST)dataContext;

                if (toggle.IsOn == true)
                {
                    dataItem.isselected = true;
                    statmentCount++;
                    cl_balance += float.Parse(dataItem.cl_blnce);

                    statmentsCount.Text = statmentCount.ToString();
                    statmentsAmount.Text = cl_balance.ToString();
                    Search_statmentsCount.Text = statmentCount.ToString();
                    Search_statmentsAmount.Text = cl_balance.ToString();

                    customersBills.Add(dataItem);
                }

                if (toggle.IsOn == false)
                {
                    dataItem.isselected = false;
                    var idx2 = BillsList.SelectedIndex;
                    statmentCount--;
                    cl_balance -= float.Parse(dataItem.cl_blnce);

                    statmentsCount.Text = statmentCount.ToString();
                    statmentsAmount.Text = cl_balance.ToString();
                    customersBills.Remove(dataItem);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog($@"{ex.Message}");
                dialog.ShowAsync().AsTask().Wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

every things goes very well

but when I use toggle switch the item toggled is added to another list( which what I want ), but i find another items got toggled ( in view only) and not add to other list when I scroll .

so any action i took on other list that containes all toggled items goes very well, but view something wrong with it

cant find why such a behavior happened to fix it

Edit

I simulated the problem as follow in a completely new app

this is the mainpage code which generate 1000 items in the listview

the Code

```
    public class test
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}



public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += CreateData;
    }

    List<test> Holders = new List<test>(); 

    public void CreateData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            test obj = new test();
            obj.id = i;
            obj.name = "Toggle";

            Holders.Add(obj);
        }

        ListObjects.ItemsSource = Holders;
    }

    private void ListObjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       
    }
}
```

}

here is the view of the main page

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="Bisque">
<Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="#FF141EE4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="ListObjects"
                  SelectionChanged="ListObjects_SelectionChanged"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                  FontFamily="Arial" 
                                  Height="250"
                  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="2">
                    <Border Margin="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SBookTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                            <ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="1" Name="SaddToBillsList" IsOn="False"  OffContent="Removed" OnContent="Added"   />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

when i select the first 3 elements for example every thing is ok

[normal selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1mIA.png)

but when i scroll down i found elements got toggled with really toggling them

[Toggle Selected without really toggling them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkE1b.png)

and when i scroll back to the first 3 items i selected at first place i found one element removed

[Scroll Back to first 3 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Octvw.png)

Comment: The problem appears to be in code you did not share (AddToBillsList_Toggled).

Comment: @RaymondChen i edited the question with the function you asked for

Comment: The problem is in something you didn't post. You'll have to debug it some more.

Comment: @RaymondChen i debugged the code and couldn't find the problem, i even removed my function and display only list of pure toggles that do nothing and the proplem keeps happening

Comment: Then maybe `BillsList_SelectionChanged` is doing something when you click on the toggle.

Comment: @RaymondChen BillsList_SelectionChanged function is responsible for items changes them self not the the toggle switch inside each item

Comment: Well, you say that something is toggling items. You need to find that thing.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes , it happens in the view only and not even fire the AddToBillsList_Toggled function

Comment: Could you please share an [mcve] about this? The code you post is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please do not share the whole project. But reproduce this in a blank project and you could share the new project with us.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT please check the Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization). It will not create all the items at the same time for the ListView when you are showing large amount of items. And sometimes it will reuse the old items. This could improve the performance.

The first way to this is that you could replace the default `ItemsStackPanel` of the **ListView**. This will disable the **UI virtualization** and this behavior will be avoided. But you will lose some performance.

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

The second way is that you need to bind the `ToggleSwitch` to a bool value inside the **ViewModel**. Using binding could reduce the probability of this happening but it can't completely disable this behavior.

```
<ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="1" Name="SaddToBillsList" IsOn="{Binding IsToggled}"  OffContent="Removed" OnContent="Added" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much first solution worked well, second one already tried it but didn't work,  thanks again

Comment: already tried but i need at least 15 reputation